# Hexadecimal number divided by 2 Program

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am newbie and I have to make a program that divides the hexadecimal number D7C3 by 2.
The correct answer is: 6be1.80
And the answer I get is: 6b e1 01

I have no idea how to fix my program so I really badly need a help. Here's my code so far:

```
mov 7Ah,#0D7h
mov 7Bh,#0C3h
mov a,7Ah
clr c
rrc a
mov 7Dh,a
mov a,7Bh
rrc a
mov 7Eh,a
clr a
addc a,#0
mov 7Fh,a
end
```

Comment: _".8"_..? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: Result should be 6be1.80

Comment: Ok, so you're storing the result in a fixed-point format. Instead of the `addc` at the end you should see if your processor has a "rotate right through carry" instruction, since what you seem to want is to place the carry in bit 7 of `a`.

Comment: thank you so much! It worked! If you want you can add this as answer so I can accept it and you can get more reputation ;)